# partial form not creating new value RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. My Question might sound weird, but i am stuck. i have a form Create that is on html page. i used `render partial`, but this form is not creating any value. here is my controller code.

**Controller.rb**

```
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


    def create
        @suppliers = current_user.suppliers.build(params[:supplier_name])
        if @suppliers.save
            flash[:success] = "Supplier Saved!"
            redirect_to 'suppliers/home'
        else
            render 'suppliers/home'
        end
     end

    def destroy
    end

    def home
        if signed_in?
            @supplier  = current_user.suppliers.build
            @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
    end
```

my **home.html.erb**

```
 <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
      <section>
        <%= render 'suppliers/suppliers_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
      <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
      <%= render 'suppliers/feed_supplier' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My **_supplier_form.html.erb** is

```
<%= form_for(@supplier)  do |f| %>

  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :supplier_name, placeholder: "Add new Supplier" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My **_feed_supplier.html.erb** is

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'suppliers/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

my **_feed_item.html.erb** is

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.supplier_name %></span>
</li>
```

please guide me to right direction, and if anything else is required then do ask. Thanks in advance

**Note**: all the mentioned files are in same folder i.e. suppliers. except the controller file

Comment: what errors r u getting?

Comment: no error, page just reloads. values arn't saving. what i see in development debug part is `controller=>home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form_for @supplier
```

will create a parameter hash like

```
{ :supplier => { :supplier_name => '[some value you put in your form]' }}
```

so the create action should use

```
@suppliers = current_user.suppliers.build(params[:supplier])
```

There is no params[:supplier_name].

Answer (score 1):

I think for the partials, you don't need to write `suppliers/*`, for example:

```
<%= render 'suppliers/suppliers_form' %>
```

could just be

```
<%= render 'suppliers_form' %>
```

not sure why that would be causing your app to do what it's doing, but worth a try!